# cloudformation validation not working locally on windows

Tags: validation, templates, aws-cloudformation, local

I'm trying to validate the cloudformation template using AWS CLI on my windows machine locally.
The command is:

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file:///C:/AWS/template.json
```

But Im getting below error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--template-body': Unable to load param file file:///C:/AWS/template.json: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file:///C:/AWS/template.json'
```

Comment: The name of the file is test.json in the command

Comment: Can you go to `/C:/AWS/` and run the command from there? `aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://template.json`

Comment: Also why one file is `test.json` and the other is `template.json`?

Comment: Yes, I tried this as well, but did not work.

Comment: The command you showed uses `file:///C:/AWS/template.json`, but error is about `'home/AWS/test.json`? While are these files different?

Comment: I'm sorry for this copy paste error.
The command I tried is: aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file:///C:/AWS/test.json
And the error is: Error parsing parameter '--template-body': Unable to load paramfile file:///C:/AWS/test.json: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/C:/AWS/test.json'

Comment: can you try `--template-body file://C:\AWS\template.json`?

Comment: Yes, I tried but still no luck.

Comment: Can you check again, I edited the comment while, you might used the original version.

Comment: I tried, but did not work

C:\AWS>aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://C:\AWS\template.json


Error parsing parameter '--template-body': Unable to load paramfile file://C:\AWS\template.json: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\AWS\\template.json'

Comment: Don't have any more ideas :-(

Comment: Anyways, Thanks for the inputs

Comment: Can also try the [Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/). Should catch more than `validate-template` anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can check permission of `AWS` directory and your `template.json` file as well.
Sometimes in Windows system directory files you have created in system drive (C://) are user permission restricted. So, It will not allow to access any created file easily.

2nd Way:

- You can upload your template to any s3 bucket and then validate your file using s3 url.
- For that, `aws cli` has valid permission for that operations.

Below is the command you can try with changing s3 URL by pointing it to your bucket and stored file:

**aws cloudformation validate-template --template-url https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/S3_Bucket.template**